# How to exclude data from an array?

Tags: php

On a product page I want to show 4 other products selected randomly, but never the product that is already being displayed. The product id of the displayed one is `$_product->getId()` and all the products go into a `$result[]` array like this:

```
foreach($collection as $product){
    $result[]=$product->getId();
}
```

I'm using `$need = array_rand($result, 4);` to get the ids of the 4 random products, but it might include the id of the product on display. How do I exclude `$_product->getId()` from the `$need[]` array? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put id of the product you don't want to show into `$result`:

```
$currentProductId = $_product->getId();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
  if ($product->getId() != $currentProductId) $result[] = $product->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable to just not put the current product ID in the array?

```
foreach($collection as $product) {
    if( $product != $_product) $result[] = $product->getId();
}
```

Comment: That should be a comment, Konlink.

Answer (score 0):

You might generate your random numbers first, like so:

```
$rands = array();
while ($monkey == false){
    $banana = rand(0,4);
    if (in_array($banana, $rands) && $banana != $_product->getId()){ $rands[] = $banana; }

    if (sizeOf($rands) == 4){
        $monkey = true;
    }

}
```

Then you could pipe them through your product grabber. Obviously, you'd need to figure out the bounds for `rand` yourself but you know more about your app than I do. Picking your numbers first is much cheaper computationally than pulling records and THEN checking to make sure that they're unique.

Of course, if this is database-backed, you could solve it much more elegantly by writing a new query.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the product id as the index `$result[]` in result, you can remove the current product from the `$result` array with `unset()` before making the call to `array_rand()` like so:

```
foreach($collection as $product){
    $result[$product->getId()] = $product->getId();
}
unset($result[$_product->getId()]);
$need = array_rand($result, 4);
```

This approach saves you from having to use the values in `$need` to look up the product id in your `$result[]` array, since the values in `$need` will be your product ids.